# Как занести данные из json в mysql

Tags: python, mysql, json

```
names = [item["name"] for item in data["organizations"]]
leaders_name = [item["leader_name"] for item in data["organizations"]]
leader_discord_id = [item["leader_discord_id"] for item in data["organizations"]]
leader_vk = [item["leader_vk"] for item in data["organizations"]]
x = {
    'name': names,
    'leader_name': leaders_name,
    'leader_discord_id': leader_discord_id,
    'leader_vk': leader_vk
}

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="",
    user="",
    password="",
    database="s424_illegals",
)
self.mycursor = self.mydb.cursor()
self.mycursor = self.mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
self.mycursor = self.mydb.cursor(dictionary=True)
curs = mydb.cursor()
curs = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
sqlFormula = 'INSERT INTO testdb (name) VALUES (%s)'
id1 = ()
curs.execute(sqlFormula, id1)
```

Comment: Покажите JSON, который надо положить в таблицу, CREATE TABLE самой таблицы, требуемый финальный результат, укажите точную версию MySQL. Почти наверняка можно не маяться фигнёй на клиенте и передать JSON на обработку в MySQL в его исходном виде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import mysql.connector

#данные извлечены
names = [...]
leaders_name = [...]
leader_discord_id = [...]
leader_vk = [...]

# подключение к MySQL
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="",
    user="",
    password="",
    database=""
)

# создание объекта курсора
curs = mydb.cursor()

# перебрать данные и вставлять каждую запись в таблицу
for i in range(len(names)):
    sqlFormula = 'INSERT INTO your_table (name, leader_name, leader_discord_id, 
leader_vk) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)'
    values = (names[i], leaders_name[i], leader_discord_id[i], leader_vk[i])
    curs.execute(sqlFormula, values)

# зафиксировать изменения
mydb.commit()
```